# 20.04 LTS ‘/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod’ not found

Tags: boot, 20.04

I just downloaded and installed Ubuntu desktop 20.04 LTS on an external 1 TB hard drive (WD my passport) but when I boot into it, i get:

```
error: file ‘/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod’ not found.
```

I used the wipe drive and install option.

And now when I boot without the drive attached it still tries to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: what drive did you originally boot from what OS did you originally have?
have you set your boot order in the bios ?

Comment: i open the startup menu to boot off the hard drive i installed on, i think i may have ovewritten my windows boot partition though, i didnt change the boot loader device in the wipe disk and install button, but linux itself is definitely on the usb hdd